# How to unit test jquery being called with Jest and Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

We have **jquery** event handler involved in **React** Component didMount lifecycle method.

The Code is Somewhat Like below:

```
export default class Home extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Usabilla("SMART_MODEM");

        $( ".option-label" ).parent().on( "click", function() {
            console.log(">>>>>>>> Click Happening.")
            let outerObject = this;

            $( ".selected" ).each(function() {
                if($(outerObject).text() !==  $(this).text()  ) {
                    $(this).click();
                }
            });
        });

         });
    }



    render() {
      // Some React Render Code Hre.
 }

}
```

I need to increase test coverage and test `$( ".option-label" ).parent().` method.

How can I unit test this method with **Jest , Enzyme and Other Relevant Technologies**?

Comment: Is it mandatory to use jquery here? How have `.option-label`s been rendered?

Comment: I am more comfortable with jquery thats why opting for it. .option_label is rendered as div here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this pure React implementation without jQuery (not implementing the whole logic of onClick). So this is easily testable:

```
state = {
  labels: []  // filled with some async operation
}

handleLabelClick = () => {
  console.log(">>>>>>>> Click Happening.")
}

renderOptionLabels = () => (
  const { labels } = this.state;

  <ul>
    {labels.length && labels.map(label => (
      <li className="option-label" key={label.id} onClick={this.handleLabelClick}>{label.text}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
)

render() {
  ...
  {this.renderOptionLabels()}
  ...
}
```